# Git, how do I get the files that are 1 commit ahead from masters to another branch

Tags: git, version-control

I need some help. Currently we are working on a project. we are using git version control to version our project. for now we have 3 branches v3.4 , v3.3 and master. the master is a 246 commits ahead on v3.4 and on master some files are still identical to v3.4.

my problem is one of my team made some changes supposed to be, for v3.4 and worked on his local master branch, then pushed everything to remote master branch, not only that, the pushed commit was mixed with updates for master and updates for v3.4 branch, another depressing is that there are 250 files pushed in 1 commit (I don't know what the **** he was thinking) with a commit message "some minor updates and fixes" (this is ****ing annoying) and he forgot what are the files specific for v3.4.

now any idea what is the easiest way to get those updates supposed to be for v3.4 that was mixed on master branch? or is it broken T_T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not work with "files", but with "snapshots" (commits). My suggestion is that you revert his commits.

You can always reset the master branch to a previous state, either by [`reverting`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) his commits - or actually reset the branch and *push --force* to your remote.

If you [`reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) it, anyone who have pulled since the unfortunate merge will still have the "bad" commits on their local branches - and might push them later on.

Comment: If I reset the head what happens to the files he modified?

Comment: How the files look on disk depends on what the current checked out commit says. If you point the branch to an earlier commit, his changes will not be visible. That is the point of a revision control system. (Same thing with the revert strategy, if you revert a commit, everything that commit introduced will be undone.)